# How to keep my buttons visible in my custom dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a custom dialog that uses an xml file to setup the layout, but my listview is pushing the buttons down so they appear to be squeezed (Those buttons do have text set). Anyone know how i could keep the buttons so they are always visible?

code: http://pastebin.com/9Mc0f8x1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi try giving the bottom linear layout weight to be 1 and also wrap all the other things above that with a linearlayout and give layout_weight property as 3 amd check....

Hope it helps you...

Comment: your information combined with this post solved it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629331/android-trying-to-understand-androidlayout-weight